# Wildfly Microservice - ELY01148: A SecurityDomain has already been associated with the specified ClassLoader

Tags: microservices, wildfly

I ran the following command:
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file /opt/wildfly/docs/examples/enable-microprofile.cli

I get the following success message after running the above script:

```
    INFO: Updating configuration to use elytron
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {
            "operation-requires-reload" => true,
            "process-state" => "reload-required"
        }
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {
            "operation-requires-reload" => true,
            "process-state" => "reload-required"
        }
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {
            "operation-requires-reload" => true,
            "process-state" => "reload-required"
        }
    }
    INFO: Removing security subsystem and ManagementRealm.
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    INFO: Adding microprofile subsystems.
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    INFO: microprofile-jwt-smallrye already in configuration, subsystem not added.
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
    }
    INFO: Configuration done.
```

Now I get the following error when I start up JBoss. The main error is ELY01148: A SecurityDomain has already been associated with the specified ClassLoader.

```
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:28,929 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    geonames-service_1  |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    geonames-service_1  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ELY01148: A SecurityDomain has already been associated with the specified ClassLoader
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.12.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityDomain.registerWithClassLoader(SecurityDomain.java:150)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.7.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.AuthenticationManager.configure(AuthenticationManager.java:91)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.applyElytronSecurity(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1242)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:957)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:276)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    geonames-service_1  |   at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    geonames-service_1  |   ... 6 more
    geonames-service_1  | 
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:28,939 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "Failed to start service
    geonames-service_1  |     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ELY01148: A SecurityDomain has already been associated with the specified ClassLoader"}}
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war" (runtime-name : "geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war")
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    geonames-service_1  | WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."geonames-service-1.0-snapshot.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    geonames-service_1  | WFLYCTL0448: 19 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,222 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 20.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 12.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 19167ms - Started 440 of 779 services (22 services failed or missing dependencies, 464 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
    geonames-service_1  | 13:54:29,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
```

Please provide any advise.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same Exception using Wildfly 25 and (with Elytron 1.17.1) using a BEARER_TOKEN as login mechanism following the quickstart:  https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/main/jaxrs-jwt

The problem happened because I use EJB and ReST Endpoint and I had different SecurityDomain for my war.

I switched securety-domain to **jwt-domain** as follow:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:9.0">
...
   <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="jwt-domain"/>
```